# BCEL - Get Class name,element names ,and method names

Tags: java, class, reverse-engineering, bcel, javaparser

how to using bcel classparaser to get class names ,element names and method names ?
ive already find a way to get class names but element and method names give me something wrong .
Anyone can help me with that ?
here is my code (with some errors there, and not completed):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.ConstantPoolGen;

public final class BcelTest
{
    // static int methods;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassParser parser;
        try
        {

            JarFile jar = new JarFile("C:\\Users\\OOO\\Desktop\\Sample.Jar");
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            ConstantPoolGen cpg = jar.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements())
            {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (!entry.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                    continue;

                parser =
                    new ClassParser("C:\\Users\\OOO\\Desktop\\Sample.Jar",
                        entry.getName());
                methods = getMethodName(cpg);

                MyClassVisitor visitor = new MyClassVisitor(parser.parse());
                visitor.start();
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getMethodName(ConstantPoolGen cpg)
    {
        return getMethodName(cpg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `parse()` on the `JavaParser` to obtain a `JavaClass` class, which offers all the required information:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Field;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;

public final class BcelTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JarFile jar = null;
        try
        {
            String jarName = "C:/theFile.jar";
            jar = new JarFile(jarName);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements())
            {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (!entry.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                ClassParser parser = 
                    new ClassParser(jarName, entry.getName());
                JavaClass javaClass = parser.parse();

                System.out.println("Class: "+javaClass.getClassName());
                System.out.println("  Fields:");
                for (Field field : javaClass.getFields())
                {
                    System.out.println("    "+field);
                }
                System.out.println("  Methods:");
                for (Method method : javaClass.getMethods())
                {
                    System.out.println("    "+method);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (jar != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    jar.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great , but how to find relationships between these classes?detect whether the class from the jar file is extending other class or if there are method calls to other class objects or other class objects are created ? see here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760153/parse-jar-file-and-find-relationships-between-classes